# configure DSN when uploading to server

Tags: php, sql-server, webserver

I have webpages mostly in PHP, ms sql database and IIS 7 server. Locally it works fine but now I'm trying to upload that to webserver using VPN and Filezilla. The problem is, what do I have to configure to get that working? On webserver there are two folders : one for webpages and one for database files. Do I have to change $host name, $username and $password in file_constants.php, or is there any other configurattions needs to be changed? Please help

I'v read instruction but there is only two lines about that, saying that I must refer to a datasource that tells the server which database to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should change hostname, username, password and database into the values your hosting has given you.